# Number of ways to divide n people into k groups with at least 2 people in each group

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I'm trying to figure out the number of ways to divide n people into k groups with at least 2 people in each group. Should I first decide a recurrence relation of the number? I don't know how I could prove such a relation.

Comment: I reckon that the persons are distinguishable. Are the groups also distinguishable (I suspect only on cardinality, but it is essential information and must be given)?

Comment: The groups are indistinguishable

Comment: Let $G(n,k)$ be the desired number.  When we add a new person, we can either add him to an existing group, or we can pair him with one of the $n$ persons, and group the remaining $n-1$ persons into $k-1$ groups of at least two people.$$G(n+1,k)=k(G(n,k)+nG(n-1,k-1)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $G(n,k)$ the number of partitions of $n$ people into $k$ groups of size $\geq2$. It is obvious that $G(n,k)=0$ if $n<2k$. Furthermore
$$G(n,1)=\left\{\eqalign{&0\qquad(n<2)\cr  &1\qquad(n\geq2)\ .\cr}\right.$$
 A recursion with respect to $k$ is obtained as follows: The oldest person among the $n$ may choose the size $j\geq 2$ of his  group  and then the other members of his group in ${n-1\choose j-1}$ ways. There are then $n-j$ people left over, which have to be partitioned into $k-1$ groups of size $\geq2$. This enforces $n-j\geq 2(k-1)$, and leads to the recursion
$$G(n,k)=\sum_{j=2}^{n+2-2k}{n-1\choose j-1}G(n-j,k-1)\qquad(n\geq2k, \ k\geq2)\ .$$
In the case $g(k):=G(2k,k)$ one obtains a closed formula with double factorials. By letting the oldest person make the first choice one immediately obtains the recursion $g(k)=(2k-1)g(k-1)$, so that $g(k)=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2k-1)$.

Comment: I see. This is really helpful! Suppose that I want to consider the special case where n=2k, is there a way to find a formula for rn,k?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: Upvoted (+1). Matches the closed form.

Answer (score 3):

We get more or less by inspection the combinatorial class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}_{=k}(\textsc{SET}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This yields per the generating function

$$G_{n,k} = n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!} (\exp(z)-z-1)^k
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!}
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^q (-1)^{k-q} z^{k-q}
\\ = n! \frac{1}{k!}
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q}
[z^{n+q-k}] (\exp(z)-1)^q (-1)^{k-q}
\\ = n! \frac{1}{k!}
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} q!
[z^{n+q-k}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q!} (-1)^{k-q}
\\ = n! \frac{1}{k!}
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} q!
\frac{1}{(n+q-k)!} {n+q-k\brace q} (-1)^{k-q}.$$

This simplifies to

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ G_{n,k} =
\sum_{q=0}^k {n\choose k-q} (-1)^{k-q} {n+q-k\brace q}.}$$

I.e. we get for $n=10$ the sequence

$$1, 501, 6825, 9450, 945, 0, \ldots$$

which  points us  to  [OEIS A008299](https://oeis.org/A008299),  where
these  data  are  confirmed  and,  incidentally,  shown to  match  the
accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a derivation of Marko Riedel's formula using the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Let $P$ be the set of partitions of your set of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ elements into $k$ groups (without the $\ge 2$ restriction). For each $i\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, let $P_i$ be the number of partitions where $i$ is in a group of size $1$. We want to count
$$
\Big|P\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n P_i\Big|.
$$
Using inclusion exclusion, and the symmetry of the numbers, this is
$$
|P|-\binom{n}1|P_1|+\binom{n}2|P_1\cap P_2|-\dots+(-1)^j\binom{n}j|P_1\cap P_2\cap \dots \cap P_j|+\dots
$$
To count $|P_1\cap P_2\cap \dots \cap P_j|$, note that elements $1,2,\dots,k$ are all alone, so we must partition the remaining $n-j$ elements into $k-j$ parts. This can be done in ${n-j \brace k-j}$ ways, by defintion of the Stirling numbers of the second kind. Therefore, the final result is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{n}j{n-j \brace k-j}
$$
Reversing the order of summation (and changing $j$ to $q$) gives Marko's answer.

Comment: Good work. Verified (+1).  For some reason I did not complete the simplification at the end. I will leave my answer as is so that your observations / concluding remarks keep making sense.

Answer (score 0):

The the number of ways in which **n** people can be divided into **k** groups of which first contain $r_1$ people, second contains $r_2$ people etc. is $\frac{n!}{r_1!r_2!...r_k!}$

Where $r_1,...r_k$ are integers such that $ r_1+r_2 +...+r_k=n,      r_i\geq 0$